# React-Material UI Grid Column issue

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

I am using React App. For styling, I am using the Material-UI library.

I fetched data from one open API and pass the data in the child component and render it to the child component. I want to show them in three-Column cards in one row. I have been trying so many ways based on Material UI documentation but could not succeed.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import moment from "moment";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  gridRoot: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    width: "390px",
    height: "200px",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: "30px",
    borderRadius: "25px"
  },
  subText: {
    fontWeight: "fontWeightMedium",
    paddingBottom: "3px",
    fontSize: "18px",
    fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed"
  }
}));

function HeroCard({ districts, source, date }) { // This is props 
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container className={classes.gridRoot} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs spacing={2}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}> //This is my Hero card.
                <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                  Health care district: {districts ? districts : "Unknown"}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                  Infection source of country: {source ? source : "Unknown"}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                  Date of infected: {moment(date).format("LLLL")}
                </Typography>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default HeroCard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understood, the code you provided is the HeroCard and you want to have all your HeroCards displayed in a grid format with 3 columns. The `<Grid container>` should be wrapping all the heroCards, not every heroCard. To achieve that I followed the source code from [this mui example](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing).

This would be the parent component that recieves the data and passes it to the heroComponent:

```js
import React from "react";
import HeroCard from "./path/to/HeroCard";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const data = [
    { id: 0, districts: "Lima", source: "COVID-19", date: "03-18-2020" },
    { id: 1, districts: "Miraflores", date: "03-18-2020" },
    { id: 2, districts: "San Isidro", date: "03-18-2020" },
    { id: 3, districts: "Surquillo", date: "03-18-2020" }
];

function App() {
    return (
        <Box p={(2, 4)}>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                {data.map((card) => (
                    <Grid key={card.id} item xs={4}>
                        <HeroCard
                            districts={card.districts}
                            source={card.source}
                            date={card.date}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and the HeroCard component would look something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import moment from "moment";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        // width: 390, // disabled width so the cards become responsive
        height: 200,
        textAlign: "center",
        padding: theme.spacing(3), // 30, // it's recommended to use theme.spacing for margins and paddings
        borderRadius: 25
    },
    subText: {
        fontWeight: "fontWeightMedium",
        paddingBottom: 3,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed"
    }
}));

function HeroCard({ districts, source, date }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                Health care district: {districts ? districts : "Unknown"}
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                Infection source of country: {source ? source : "Unknown"}
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.subText}>
                Date of infected: {moment(date).format("LLLL")}
            </Typography>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default HeroCard;
```

Some considerations & personal recomendations:

- Use [prop-types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) so you and other people reading your code know the types of the props that each component receives. That's just one of the many benefits.
- Mui transforms `height: 200` to `height: "200px"`; [more info](https://material-ui.com/system/sizing/#supported-values).

Good luck! :)

Comment: You don't know. How much you helped me. Thanks a lot 

Comment: Now another issue raised, My mobile versions also show three columns cards, it looks bad. How can I show one card in mobile version? I was looking for media query in Material-UI but did not find any good solution. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Glad that I helped. I highly encourage you to read [the Mui guide](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#how-it-works) and try to understand how most things work before implementing them. The grid component uses 5 breakpoints. You can indicate the column-width size every grid item should have at each breakpoint like that: `<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>`, more info [here](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid-with-breakpoints) (notice how the items labeld `xs=12 sm=6` adjust below 600px). More info about breakpoints [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints).

Comment: Thank you too. Turns out my issue was that the admin template I was using had their own Grid System which I mistook for Material UI's. Problem fixed. Mucho gracias